# Python38 altinstall ensurepip fails

Tags: python-3.x, linux, rhel7

Redhat 7.4  
Base python2.7 
Existing python3.6 already installed

Attempting altinstall Python3.8.12 fails with error info below.  
Can anyone help with what the root cause is ?  
Any help greatly appreciated.

Installation is air gapped so .tgz is downloaded and SCPd to server. Installation is run as root.
I can't publish full stacktrace due to size restriction unfortunately.

Config customised for SSL

```
SSL=/usr/local/ssl

_ssl _ssl.c \
        -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
        -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install
```

```
make altinstall
```

resulting error

```
if test "xinstall" != "xno"  ; then \

        case install in \

                upgrade) ensurepip="--altinstall --upgrade" ;; \

                install|*) ensurepip="--altinstall" ;; \

        esac; \

         ./python -E -m ensurepip \

                $ensurepip --root=/ ; \

fi

*** Error in `/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/python': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000eb4a80 ***

======= Backtrace: =========

/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c619)[0x7fe5d7d77619]

/usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1(EVP_MD_CTX_reset+0xa4)[0x7fe5d8220704]

/usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1(EVP_MD_CTX_free+0x9)[0x7fe5d8220759]

/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/_hashlib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x298b)[0x7fe5ce80b98b]

/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x268e)[0x428d0e]
```

lots of errors here,

```
======= Memory map: ========

00400000-0072a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 740168                             /usr/src/Python-3.8.12/python

00929000-0092a000 r--p 00329000 fd:00 740168                             /usr/src/Python-3.8.12/python

0092a000-00969000 rw-p 0032a000 fd:00 740168                             /usr/src/Python-3.8.12/python
```

etc

```
7fe5cd501000-7fe5cd502000 r--p 0000c000 fd:00 12728288                   /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1

7fe5cd502000-7fe5cd503000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:00 127282Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/Lib/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main

    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,

  File "/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/Lib/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code

    exec(code, run_globals)

  File "/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>

    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())

  File "/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 206, in _main

    return _bootstrap(

  File "/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 125, in _bootstrap

    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)

  File "/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 34, in _run_pip

    return subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", code], check=True).returncode

  File "/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/Lib/subprocess.py", line 516, in run

    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/src/Python-3.8.12/python', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'/tmp/tmpu8hywfjm/setuptools-56.0.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'/tmp/tmpu8hywfjm/pip-21.1.1-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'/tmp/tmpu8hywfjm\', \'--root\', \'/\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.

make: *** [altinstall] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it seems that we need to run the commands as root: `sudo <command>`.